# Object class of every type in Java

Tags: java, object

How can I create a class Object of any type ( string, char, int, float, double. short, long, byte,...) so that i can use a linkedlist list that accept everty type of the class Object

Comment: In Java all classes extends Object. SO why you wanna do it again?

Comment: Sounds like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What do you actually want to do with that list once you have it?

Comment: I have to serialize the object of the list in string

Answer (score 2):

The class object that is compatible with anything in Java is `Object.class`. If you make a `LinkedList<Object>`, you would be able to put anything into it.

Note that primitive values, such as `float`, `int`, etc. would be stored in their object wrappers, i.e. [`Float`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html), [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), etc. This fact may be hidden by autoboxing, but generic Java collections cannot store primitives directly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store actual primitive values in a `LinkedList`, you may have to wait until Java 10, when project Valhalla might be implemented. You would then be able to instanciate `new LinkedList<int>()`, etc. Read the State of the Specialization document here:

- http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/valhalla/specialization.html

For the time being, [Trove4j](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/html/overview.html) is a Java project that implements specialised collections for primitive types, such as [`TIntList`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/TIntList.html), for instance. Or you can put boxed types in your `LinkedList`, [as others have mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28010606/521799).

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Object> ll = new LinkedList<Object>();
ll.add(new String("aaa"));
ll.add(new Integer(123));
```